# C# Custom Exception Title in MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, messagebox

The title is a tad confusing, so hopefully I can explain it a tad better here. I want to change the title of the MessageBox that pops up on the screen if there is an error, since the default message is extremely long winded and I'd prefer to give a better explanation for the error that the user could understand.

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Department Staff")
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = dataSource.DataTableQuery("SELECT * FROM DepartmentStaff");
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable To Connect To Database, Please Try Again Later.", ex.ToString());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = dataSource.DataTableQuery("SELECT * FROM Department");
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable To Connect To Database, Please Try Again Later.", ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Would this require me to create a custom exception?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this Winforms? WPF? ASP.Net?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What _specifically_ is your difficulty? You are already calling the `MessageBox.Show()` overload that allows you to specify a caption. Just specify the caption you want, instead of the entire exception `ToString()` result. What problem are you having?

Comment: I believe, what he means is that he has a very long *caption* (he terms it as *title*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look more carefully on the `Message.Show()` arguments:

```
Message.Show(text, caption); //the first one is text, the second one is caption.
```

The second argument is the **caption** (or title) while the *first* one is the message. Now in your use, you put up your exception message (which typically is very long) as the **caption** and that's why you get an *"extremely long winded"* **caption** (not **message**).

```
MessageBox.Show("Unable To Connect To Database, Please Try Again Later.", ex.ToString());
```

*Don't* do that! Instead, do it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Unable To Connect To Database, Please Try Again Later. " +  ex.ToString(), "Error");
```

Simply put "Error" as caption argument.

Comment: @BenParry you are welcome. Hope you can progress well using the `MessageBox.Show`.